# Why is this C++ code of linkedlist insertion giving segmentation fault?

Tags: c++, linked-list

I have written two functions for insertion at the beggining and insertion at the end in LinkedList. But, it shows segmentation fault. Why my code is giving segmentation fault?

```
/*Structure of the linked list node is as
struct Node {
  int data;
  struct Node * next;
  Node(int x) {
    data = x;
    next = NULL;
  }
}; */

// function inserts the data in front of the list
Node *insertAtBegining(Node *head, int newData) {
   Node* newnode;
   newnode->data = newData;
   newnode->next = head;
   head = newnode;
   return head;
}


// function appends the data at the end of the list
Node *insertAtEnd(Node *head, int newData)  {
   Node* newnode;
   newnode->data = newData;
   newnode->next = NULL;
   Node* temp;
   temp = head;
   while(temp->next!=NULL){
       temp = temp->next;
   }
   temp->next = newnode;
   return head;
}
```

Comment: What line seg faults? That would be very helpful to us. Also, there's no main method so we cannot reproduce your problem.

Comment: newnode is local variable in both functions, stack allocated. So it will die when the scope is finished.

Answer (score 0):

newnode is local variable in both functions, stack allocated. So it will die when the scope is finished.

You must allocate a new memory area from  heap, not stack.

Solution :

```
Node* newnode = (Node*)calloc(sizeof(Node),1);
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> Node* newnode;
> newnode->data = newData;
> newnode->next = head;
> ```

Here you indirect through an indeterminate pointer as if it pointed to an object. The behaviour of the program is unrefined.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really know where a pointer points to and you should never try to access data to it before you pointed it to an actual address or allocate memory for it. It is a good practice to declare pointers to null to avoid mistakes like this.
example:

```
Node* newnode = NULL;
newnode = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
ewnode->data = newData;
newnode->next = head;
```

Or of course all this in on line.
And don't forget to free the memory